# kendo window load aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Please can somebody explain how I can open up an ASPX page that is in my solution in a Kendo UI Window and get any values that I need?

What I want is to open a Kendo window with my own ASPX page which will pass an ID through to the main view after a template has been selected in the Kendo Window.

Answer (score 0):

[This demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/ajax.html) shows how to load a remote page into the contents of a Window by using the `content` property:

```
window.kendoWindow({
    content: "myPage.aspx"
});
```

Though by default it expects just HTML that it will inject into your page, so the result should not contain `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags. However at that point the markup is just insterted into the page, so any JavaScript can directly communicate with the "parent" because they are all the same page.

---

You could also specify the `iframe` option

```
window.kendoWindow({
    content: "myPage.aspx",
    iframe: true
});
```

which will make the window contents an `<iframe>` instead of injecting it into the page.
I think your contents then could specify the `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags just like a normal page, but now your JavaScript would have to do something different to pass a value back to the parent. That is back in the realm of normal JS, not Kendo. If I remember correctly, you can call a function in your iframe's parent by calling:

```
window.parent.myFunction("some value");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this... I've tried it and it just gives me HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. Any Ideas... I took the exact same code and from the ASPX section and just replaced it with my test ASPX page.

Comment: Check the dev tools in the web browser and see what URL it is requesting? Make sure the URL is right and that Kendo isn't messing it up somehow.

Comment: it does say src=ViewPage1.aspx for the iframe. Not sure what is happening.